# Add New tag "lightning-out" in SFSE

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see lot of question being asked on **Lightning Out** and every time users post such questions, many don't add the information that Lightning Component is run inside a VF container only few does it, and most of such question's first comment from the users who are trying to answer the question is:

*Are you running the component inside VF page?*

I think it's time to introduce the new tag, so users can tag it if such question arises by editing/posting the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag [exists and was created a year ago](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/lightning-out/info). Feel free to apply it anywhere you see it missing. You already have enough rep to edit posts without going into a review queue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, when I searched for it I couldn't find it in all tag section. Anyway, Thank you for the reply.